# Schedule / Run AWS Lambda invocation with specific request every 3 hours

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

There is an external API that has some data that I need to have a copy of inside a dynamoDB table.

The external API gives me an user_id and some user_data. There are many user_ids that need to be updated on a regular basis (every few hours).

I can easily invoke the function to get the data initially into the table and record the first batch (as each user_id is added manually).

But how can I schedule the lambda function, to run again, with the user ID as a parameter, to update the record automatically, 3 hours after it's been added to the table?

I was thinking about some 'scheduler_table' to which to save a timestamp with when the next update should be and for which user_id, and then having a trigger that invokes a lambda function every 10 minutes to scan the table, to see if there are any 'expired' timestamps, but this seems sub-optimal and I was wondering if there are any AWS resources, design decisions or methods I can use, that will allow me to do this in a more straight-forward and easy to manage manner?

If the dynamoDB scheduler_table solution is reasonable, what would be the best way to organize the primary/sort keys and how would I go about querying them? (as I've found out that scanning wouldn't be a great solution)

PS: Solutions are not too hard on my pokets are preferred.

Thanks!

Comment: You can add cron jobs in Amazon EventBridge. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-get-started.html

Comment: This is what I have in the Rules section for my function: Cron expression
1 10 * * ? *
Next 10 trigger date(s)

GMT
Fri, 25 Mar 2022 10:01:00 GMT
Sat, 26 Mar 2022 10:01:00 GMT
Sun, 27 Mar 2022 10:01:00 GMT
Mon, 28 Mar 2022 10:01:00 GMT
Tue, 29 Mar 2022 10:01:00 GMT
Wed, 30 Mar 2022 10:01:00 GMT
Thu, 31 Mar 2022 10:01:00 GMT
Fri, 01 Apr 2022 10:01:00 GMT
Sat, 02 Apr 2022 10:01:00 GMT
Sun, 03 Apr 2022 10:01:00 GMT

I do not recall the specifics.

Comment: What about the user_id? When hundreds of user IDs get added, will cron jobs be sustainable to be added for each user_id?

Comment: Uh, oh. :) I should have said nothing. :)

Comment: DDB is good solution, but maybe [ttl](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html) would be useful as you could set ttl to each user for 3h after each update.  But TTL is not garuanteed to fire exactly on time, it can be delayed up to 48 hours. So it depends how critical is your 3h time frame.

Comment: I can't risk having stale data. As you said, ttl might work well, but there may be substantial delay